# Obtain magnetic field strength $H$ of a condenser

Tags: electromagnetism, dielectric

**Context:**
*I wish to know how to get the magnetic field strength (H) in a surface point of the condenser made by  2 circular plates separated by a dielectric which is a perfect insulator with a uniform field (D), assuming that it's an ideal condenser.*

**My work so far:**

I think that I can use Maxwell's version of Ampere's law **[Curl of H = current density (J) + dD/dt]**.

Using  Stoke's theorem I can transform the equation to **[Line Integral of (H) = Current (I) + D x (Area between the circles)]**

I want to know if i'm correct and how to get rid of the line integral to obtain **(H)**.

Answer (score 0):

You have found the useful one of Maxwell's equations. The current density term is probably radial on a capacitor plate, it's perpendicular with the surface normal so it's effect to the surface integral which you should calculate to get the line integral is zero.

The growth rate of the electric flux density is the charging current of the capacitor divided by the plate area. You need the growth rate to calculate the line integral of H as a surface integral.

The line integral of H along a circle at distance r from the plate midpoint is 2Pi * r * H. You get H at distance r by calculating the surface integral of curl(H) over a circle which has radius=r and by dividing the result with (2Pi * r).